# shell script load jar files and hang

Tags: shell, jar, cron, load, runtime

Good day,

I have a shell script, which will load some jar files first before proceed to do its job. The following is part of my shell script code to load jar files:

```
for f in `find $BASEDIR/lib -type f -name "*.jar"` 
do 
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$f
  echo Getting  jar file : $f... >> $LOG
done
```

This is working fine when I trigger this through `Crontab`, I set a time in `crontab` and let it trigger automatically, and its work without any error.

However, I having some problem when I trigger this shell script through application run time. Here is my java code to trigger this shell script:

```
try {
  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myShell.sh");
  log.debug("Successfully invoked batch.");
} catch (Exception ex) {

  log.info("Hit error : "
      + ex.getMessage());

  return false;
}
```

I checked the log that I put in the shell script, and found that its hang when trying to getting "xstream-1.4.9.jar" (during run time call). But `crontab` call have no issue.

And another weird thing is, I have 2 same environment, which is environment 1 and environment 2, and this issue only happen in environment 2, checked through all the permission, they are the same.

Can anyone advise how I can continue to troubleshoot on this?

Comment: i think when you run script in java it will not pass any env variables like $CLASSPATH.

Comment: the $CLASSPATH actually defined is beginning line on the shell script, so it actually contain value. And even $CLASSPATH is empty, I think it will not hang also.